# Can We Input Return Using Shell Scripts?

Tags: shell-script, shell, ubuntu, useradd

I want to use `adduser USER` (USER is a user name), but this asks me many questions like full name and address. I want a script which types the return key automatically and skip those questions. For example, I execute `./myadduser.sh USER` and myadduser.sh call adduser USER and input return to all questions. Is there a great way to do this? I am thinking about Ubuntu 14.04.

Sorry, I made a mistake. Input return not to all questions since I have to input password which cannot be return. Is it possible to input return to all questions except questions about password?

Comment: `yes "" | adduser ...`

Comment: Look at `adduser --help` and you'll see all those can be passed in a single line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `yes` command continuously outputs the first argument provided followed by a newline until stopped. So this should work for you: `yes "" | adduser ...`.

However, most modern programs have similar things built in already, or make it so that you can pass all needed information on the command line, to make it script-friendly. I believe this is the case with `adduser` on Ubuntu.